# Java: Are there any built-in classes in Java/Android that implements the Serializable interface?

Tags: java, android, serialization, casting

Are there any default classes in the Java or Android SDK that implements the Serializable interface, such that when that class is instantiated, its object can be casted to Serialisable? Or are all classes that implement the Serializable interface custom classes?

Comment: Maybe try reading [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)?

Comment: `java.lang.String`

Comment: @Ivan good call!

Comment: What's a "default class"?

Answer (score 1):

There are many classes that implement `Serializable`, most common are things like primitive wrappers(`Integer`,`Double`,`Character` etc.), data classes, full list for built-in java classes that implement this interface can be found here(for Java 8):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/class-use/Serializable.html

Not sure if there is any list about Android really, but google search would probably help you better than I can.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question.

```
        Serializable s = new Integer(1); // ok
        Serializable t=  new Thread(); // error
```

Not all the java objects needs to implement the Serializable interface. We will not serialize the things like thread.

See More: [Why doesn't Java.lang.Object implement the Serializable Interface?](http://Why%20doesn't%20Java.lang.Object%20implement%20the%20Serializable%20Interface?)